# MyBatis - Disable cache

Tags: java, mysql, orm, mybatis, ibatis

I need to disable the cache of MyBatis because I'm altering my database in other ways and want that MyBatis has always the latest version of my data ready.
I tried numerous ways to disable it:

- Calling `SqlSession.clearCache()` before every query
- Adding `<setting name="cacheEnabled" value="false" />` to mybatis-config.xml
- Adding `<setting name="localCacheScope" value="STATEMENT" />` to mybatis-config.xml
- Adding `@Options(flushCache = Options.FlushCachePolicy.TRUE, useCache = false)` to every statement

Nothing works and I always get old data on queries.

Comment: Never had that problem. Are you sure the data was committed by the other thread?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, I am sure. And when I restart my MyBatis implementation it just finds the new records.

Comment: I use MyBatis regularly and I've never faced this problem. I think caching is disabled by default, but I may be wrong. Is there any way I could reproduce the case, so I can debug it? It worries me, since I use it extensively.

Comment: This might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440362/mybatis-how-to-bypass-a-local-cache-and-directly-hit-the-db-on-specific-select)